# UIGestureRecognizer blocking TableView Editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `TableView` in editing mode. When I want to move the `TableViewCell`, the gesture blocks it. How can I disable this?

**I only want to disable the Gesture Recognizer when the user drags a cell using the UITableViewCellReorderControl.**

[The Code Repository on GitHub.](https://github.com/evenwerk/TableView-Editing-Gesture-Recognizer.git)

[image: A gif visualising the problem.]

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded your project from Git . Please use `gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false` in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: The cell is movable but the gesture code is still being executed. How can I prevent that?

Comment: You have added the gesture on whole view. So your gesture method will be called until you remove the gesture when cell is moving. Hope it helps

Comment: How can I detect the movement of the cell? I want to disable it when the cell is moving.

Comment: 'moveRowAt sourceIndexPath' use this method. Moreover don't remove and add everytime. Use enabled property of UIPanGesture.

Comment: This method is called when the cell is moved. What method can I use before the cell is being moved?

Comment: I think it's not possible as you have added pangesture. So touches will pass from pangesture first down the line to subview in hierarchy. That blocking of moving the cell can be only resolved .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151909/discussion-between-tim-e-and-aditya-srivastava).